# Can't access the data pre-populated in an a Angularjs form input using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium

Here is the html:

```
<form class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-hide="loading" name="profileForm" ng-submit="saveStudent()" novalidate="" style="">
  <div ng-hide="profileSaved">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" required="" ng- model="data.Student.FirstName" name="FirstName">
```

I'm trying to verify the pre-populated contents of the input fields.  I've seen a few suggestions that mention using getAttribute("value").  I've tried using:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("FirstName")).getAttribute("value");`
```

and I tried using:

```
String str = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('FirstName').value;").toString();
```

Nothing is returned and that's what I would expect since the input doesn't have a value attribute.  I also have problems clearing the input field or changing the data using sendKeys().  I can move to the input and click using:

```
inputs.moveToElement(fname).click(fname).perform();
```

Any ideas on how I can access the values of the pre-populated form?

I also noticed something else odd about the interaction with the input field.   If I do the following:

```
inputs.moveToElement(fname1).click(fname1).sendKeys(fname1, "test").perform();
String str2 = fname1.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("text2 is: "+str2);
```

The value of str2 is "test", but only the default value is displayed in the input field.  If I do this:

```
fname1.clear();
inputs.moveToElement(fname1).click(fname1).sendKeys(fname1, "test").perform();
String str2 = fname1.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("text2 is: "+str2);
```

str2 is still "test", but the page displays the default value + test in the input field(e.g. "FirstNametest")

Comment: are you using protractor?

Comment: I'm using protractor and selenium.  I'm supporting two different technology stacks and I'm having the same problem with verifying the default form data.  I'm able to use protractor in for one stack because it's a pure angular app.  The second app requires a login from a non-angular app, so I am using selenium webdriver and java.

Comment: I've had issues where I had to use WebDriverWait wait.until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("elementId")));  it may be a race condition where the form data Isn't available at the time of the query (which has happened to me a lot in angular before protractor. Just a suggestion

Comment: I tried this: 
`WebElement fname1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/form/div/input[1]")));`

Comment: but still had the same problem.